# Expected text file lines after saving with "writeLines" python method

Tags: python, file, csv, io

I am trying to split a large CSV file into several parts as files with **Python**.
as a first try, I read the first **261579** lines from the CSV dataset file using this part of the code:

```
    for c in range(261579):
        line = datasetFile.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:print("empty line detected at : " ,c)
        lines.append(line)
    print("SAVING LINES ......")
    split = open(outputDirectoryName+"spilt" + str(x+1) +".csv","w")
    split.writelines(lines)
    print("SPLIT " + str(x+1) + " END with " ,str(len(lines)) , "lines .")
```

OK, for the moment, the code works well and shows me

> "SPLIT 1 END with 261579 lines."

, But the problem is that when I open my file "Split1.csv" with notpad++,  I only find **261575** instead of **261579**, it's a loss of data for 4 lines somewhere in the file.

With this proportion, I want to know what exactly happens with the "file.writeLines (lines)" method when do we use it to save my data in a split file?

Comment: Why not use the csv module for this?

Comment: Thank you AMC for replay, given that my goal is to split the file and not process its data, I exclude the use of this tool. Also, these tools are not well suited to what I do due to the fact that the file I am processing is very large, which imposes restrictions that cause me to skip this tool. please let's focus on this problem if you understand my subject and my restrictions as well, please, can you give me another solution?

Comment: _given that my goal is to split the file and not process its data, I exclude the use of this tool._ I'm not sure how the csv module is a poor fit due to the nature of the task. _Also, these tools are not well suited to what I do due to the fact that the file I am processing is very large, which imposes restrictions that cause me to skip this tool._ Why do you say that? As long as you're iterating in the same way, the csv module should make virtually no difference on the memory consumption of the program.

Comment: By the way, you haven't provided a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue and then I found out that I should have closed my file.for you

```
split.close()
```

Comment: My feelings are indescribable to this answer. Really, thank you very much.

Comment: @MedMahdiMaarouf Both of you should have used context managers, you could have avoided the problem entirely.

Comment: @AMC Thank you again, while awaiting the response from my program. The latter helped me in examining some of the data that are being dealt in the background of the program in a smooth manner. I will use it on my next projects, thanks for the benefit.